# Displaying and switching between ViewControllers in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm basically trying to create a custom UITabBarController since I need some specific functionality. The TabBar itself is done and working, but I don't quite know how to display ViewControllers in this `CustomTabBarViewController` itself.

Assuming i have the following method:

```
func tabSelected(_ index: Int) {}
```

and  knowing the height of my TabBar through `tabbar.frame.size`, how do I instantiate two ViewControllers above the TabBar and switch between them when the `tabSelected` method is called? A transition animation would be even nicer, but not really necessary.

NOTE: my TabBar doesn't inherit from `UITabBarController`, only from the regular `UIViewController`, to avoid further confusion.

Comment: How do you present ViewControllers? Do you use segues? Do you have array of ViewControllers and you just presenting them? Do you use Contrainer View?

Comment: @RobertDresler that's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm pretty new to ios dev, so I didnt know how exactly you would display a viewcontroller in another viewcontroller, but I don't think a simple container would do the trick, since you need to instantiate both ViewControllers and display one at a time depending on the currently selected tab. In the usual iOS TabBarController its obviously easy since you just drag segues to the corresponding viewcontrollers you want to have as tabs.

Comment: Do you use Storyboard?

Comment: @RobertDresler well yes, it's just that my tabbar is a simple UIView in my "main" view controller, what i have to figure out now is how to display the others in that main viewcontroller above the tabbar

Comment: "Child view controllers" is the relevant concept here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created sample project:
[CustomTabBarViewController](https://github.com/RobertDresler/CustomTabBarViewController)

---

- You should have container view for child ViewControllers
- Then you should have array with embed ViewControllers
- You should call method in
  `CustomTabBarViewController` which change ViewController inside
  container view to ViewController from array of VCs at index which you pass as parameter of this method

---

Start with declaring outlet collection for your TabBar buttons and also get reference for container view where your ViewControllers will be showed

```
@IBOutlet var tabBarButtons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
```

then create array for your tab bar items

```
var items: [UIViewController]?
```

next create lazy variables for your controllers

```
private lazy var aVC: A = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "a") as! A
}()

private lazy var bVC: B = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "b") as! B
}()
```

*.... this can be simplified by creating method which returns ViewController depending on VC’s identifier*

After that append ViewControllers to your `items` array and also each add as `child` of your TabBarViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    items = [aVC, bVC]
    items!.forEach { addChild($0) }
}
```

continue with declaring method for setting ViewController

```
private func setViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    items!.forEach { $0.view.removeFromSuperview(); $0.willMove(toParent: nil) }
    container.addSubview(viewController.view)
    viewController.view.frame = container.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

now add action for your tab bar buttons and get index of button. Then with this index call your `tabSelected` method

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let index = tabBarButtons.index(of: sender) {
        tabSelected(index)
    }
}
```

inside `tabSelected` set VC from `items` depending on index of sender tab bar button

```
func tabSelected(_ index: Int) {
    if let item = items?[index] {
        setViewController(item)
    }
}
```

finally in `viewDidLoad` set first item

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    tabSelected(0)
}
```

---

Now you can fully customize your ViewController and make other epic stuff which you know from `UITabBarController`

Comment: I think you didn't quite understand. My custom TabBar doesn't inherit from `UITabBarController`, so I need to completely replicate it's View switching mechanics.

Comment: @just_deko check edited answer, if something is unclear, feel free to ask. :-)

Comment: @just_deko I'd created demo and pushed it on GitHub . Link above in top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

**1.** In your `CustomTabBarViewController` define an array to hold the ViewControllers:

```
var viewControllers: [UIViewController]
```

Instantiate the view controllers and add them to the array:

```
// If you're not using storyboard:
let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
// If using storyboard:
let searchViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController")

viewControllers = [homeViewController, searchViewController, ...]
```

**2.** Define a variable to keep track of the tab button that is selected:

```
var selectedIndex: Int = 0
```

**3.** Implement your `tabSelected` method like so. I've explained each line in code:

```
func tabSelected(_ index: Int) {
    let previousIndex = selectedIndex

    selectedIndex = index

    // Use previousIndex to access the previous ViewController from the viewControllers array.
    let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]

    // Remove the previous ViewController
    previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

    // Use the selectedIndex to access the current ViewController from the viewControllers array.
    let vc = viewControllers[selectedIndex]

    // Add the new ViewController (Calls the viewWillAppear method of the ViewController you are adding)
    addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds

    // contentView is the main view above your tab buttons
    contentView.addSubview(vc.view)

    // Call the viewDidAppear method of the ViewController you are adding using didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```